# Is threre any better way to accomplish this using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I am trying to hide all elements `when one button is clicked and only the menu belonging to that specific button should appear`.
If I do like this that will be too long if more buttons and menus are there.

Are there any methods that can shorten this and get the desired result?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#steps").click(function(){
        $("#calculateMenu").hide();
        $("#stepsMenu").show();    
    });

    $("#calculate").click(function(){ 
        $("#stepsMenu").hide(); 
        $("#calculateMenu").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: using a class instead of ids?

Comment: I would suggest including a snippet of the `html` which will help with understanding the UI/layout.

Comment: how is your HTML content? does steps and calculate elements contain other elements?

Comment: @mehmetx they will show button with links on another div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$("#steps,#calculate").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("[id*=Menu]").hide();
  $("#" + id + "Menu").show();
});
```

All element where id contains `Menu` will be hidden, and then we will show the "correct" element

**Demo**

```js
$("#steps,#calculate").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("[id*=Menu]").hide();
  $("#" + id + "Menu").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="steps">steps</button>
<button id="calculate">calculate</button>



<div id="stepsMenu">stepsMenu</div>
<div id="calculateMenu">calculateMenu</div>
```

Comment: Similar, you could also use data- attributes to link your(OPs) button/menu rather than give ID [meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute#:~:text=identifiers%20are%20opaque%20strings)

Comment: `$("#steps,#calculate")` What happens if we add one more button? As a result, We have to adjust the script, bro. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66704666/9071943) with `data-attributes` to link between `button/menu` combined with `class` selector

Comment: @Phong First I know that he would have to adjust the script. Second don't call me bro. Third he didn't say that would be a problem, OP asked for a way to shorten the script, nothing else.

Comment: Hi, @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just want to discuss diving deeper inside into the problem. Sorry If I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Phong I don't mind discussing stuff, but as you can see the OP writes `Is there any methods which can shorten this and get the desired result?`. Both of ours answers are correct in each own way.

Answer (score 0):

> When one button is clicked and the only menu belonging to that specific
> button should appear

As [@freedomn-m 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703910/is-threre-any-better-way-to-accomplish-this-using-jquery/66704666#comment117913773_66703938),

You can use [`data-attributes`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to link between `button and menu` combined with `class` selector like below:

```js
$(".Mybutton").click(function() {
  var activeMenu = $(this).data('buttonname');
  $(".menu").hide();
  $("#" + activeMenu).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='Mybutton' data-buttonname='steps'>steps</button>
<button class='Mybutton' data-buttonname='calculate'>calculate</button>
<button class='Mybutton' data-buttonname='finish'>finish</button>

<div class='menu' id="steps">stepsMenu</div>
<div class='menu' id="calculate">calculateMenu</div>
<div class='menu' id="finish">finishMenu</div>
```